# Terminal missing in Mac OS X?

Tags: macbook, terminal.app

I am new to Mac OS. It seems cool, but I can't find terminal cmd utility on my Macbook. Is there any other way to find it or any other third party terminals available?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a shell on a Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/178735/how-do-you-get-a-shell-on-a-mac)

Comment: On Mac OS X, we have no `cmd`, we have *the Terminal*. :-)

Answer (score 17):

You should be able to find it in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal

Or you could use Spotlight (the magnifying glass icon in the top right) - click it (or press CMD+Space) and then start typing what you're after

Comment: strangely enough, after updating to High Sierra - Terminal stopped showing up in spotlight but it is still in the folder.

Answer (score 3):

Another interesting app is [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

I found it's under Utilities now in my application folder. I've copied it to Applications folder and it's now visible in my Spotlight again.

Answer (score -1):

I arrived here from a google search because the terminal randomly and inexplicably went missing from the screen! Nothing I did brought it back, yet it was still active since processes on local host were still running fine.

To get it back, find it in the dock (a black square icon), click on it and select one (any) of the processes, and it will come back on screen. Hope this might be helpful to anyone else in this rare and weird situation!

Comment: -1 - the terminal app is not always in the dock